# Save old value of a cell in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have create this macro finding pieces around and suiting it to my program:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("N19")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

        Dim vNew As Integer
        Dim vOld As Integer
        vNew = Range("N19").Value
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Undo
        vOld = Range("N19").Value
        Range("N19").Value = vNew
        Range("D159").Value = vOld
        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If
End Sub
```

I need to save the old value of N19 in D159.

Do you know why it is not working?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the place of the assigning of value to `vOld`. In your code, it was assigned to `N19` after the `Application.Undo`, thus it is assigned to nothing. I have tried this, it worked:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("N19")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then

        Dim vNew As Long
        Dim vOld As Long

        vNew = Range("N19")
        vOld = Range("N19")
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Undo
        vOld = Range("N19")
        Range("N19") = vNew
        Range("D159") = vOld

        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If
End Sub
```